# Arrange given numbers to form the biggest number

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, comparator

For a given number I want to generate the biggest number from the number's digits.

For example: Input: 3134059 The largest number is: 9543310 And the smallest number is: 1033459

Errors:

```
Main.java:18: error: ';' expected
        public int compare(String X,String Y){
                          ^
Main.java:18: error: ';' expected
        public int compare(String X,String Y){
                                          ^
Main.java:18: error: not a statement
        public int compare(String X,String Y){
                                           ^
Main.java:18: error: ';' expected
        public int compare(String X,String Y){
                                            ^
4 errors
```

Code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter The Size of Array");
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        String[] arr=new String[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            arr[i]=sc.nextString();
        }
        printLargest(arr);

    }
    static void printLargest(String[] arr){
        Arrays.sort(arr, new Comparator<String>());
        @Override
        public int compare(String X,String Y){
            String XY=X+Y;
            String YX=Y+X;
            return XY.compareTo(YX)?1:-1;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            System.out.print(arr[i]+" ");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: it looks like you tried to use an anonymous inner class to override the compare method but didn't quite do it. Look up the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Coorect Way to use Comparator interface and its only method that is compare()

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter The Size of Array");
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        String[] arr=new String[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            arr[i]=Integer.toString(sc.nextInt());
        }
        Arrays.sort(arr, new newComparator());
        for(int i=n-1;i>=0;i--){
            System.out.print(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
class newComparator implements Comparator<String>{
        public int compare(String X,String Y){
            String XY=X+Y;
            String YX=Y+X;
            System.out.print(XY+" : ");
            System.out.print(YX);
            System.out.println();
            int a=Integer.parseInt(XY);
            int b=Integer.parseInt(YX);
            if(a==b) return 0;
            else if(a>b) return 1;
            else return -1;
        }
}
```

Comment: You do not need a `Comparator` for this requirement.